# How efficient is using assembly in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, assembly, freepascal, lazarus

I'm working on a graphical application where it requires elementary matrix and vector operations (e.g. multiplication, subtract, add, dot product, cross prodcut etc..). What I want to know is, whether I can benefit from performance in terms of speed by converting those elementary routines to assembly codes in Lazarus (FPC 2.4.4). I'm bit afraid of attempting to over-optimizing the code which is not recommended by the experts.

Along with that, below is the truncated code snippet, the function name `function MultiplyTransform2D(const M1, M2: TTransf2D): TTransf2D;` is irrelevant here, how to start assembly coding of the below snippet, a few lines of sample will be appreciated,

```
 TTransf2D = array[1..3, 1..3] of TRealType;

function MultiplyTransform2D(const M1, M2: TTransf2D): TTransf2D;
var
  B1, B2: Boolean;
begin
  B1 := (M1[1, 3] = 0.0) and (M1[2, 3] = 0.0) and (M1[3, 3] = 1.0);
  B2 := (M2[1, 3] = 0.0) and (M2[2, 3] = 0.0) and (M2[3, 3] = 1.0);
  if B1 and B2 then
   begin
     Result[1, 1] := M1[1, 1] * M2[1, 1] + M1[1, 2] * M2[2, 1];
     Result[1, 2] := M1[1, 1] * M2[1, 2] + M1[1, 2] * M2[2, 2];
     Result[1, 3] := 0.0;

     Result[2, 1] := M1[2, 1] * M2[1, 1] + M1[2, 2] * M2[2, 1];
     Result[2, 2] := M1[2, 1] * M2[1, 2] + M1[2, 2] * M2[2, 2];
     Result[2, 3] := 0.0;

     Result[3, 1] := M1[3, 1] * M2[1, 1] + M1[3, 2] * M2[2, 1] + M2[3, 1];
     Result[3, 2] := M1[3, 1] * M2[1, 2] + M1[3, 2] * M2[2, 2] + M2[3, 2];
     Result[3, 3] := 1.0;
   end
  else if B1 and (not B2) then
```

Comment: For starters, you could look at the assembly generated by the compiler for the portable Pascal implementation (turn optimizations on). If you can spot obvious deficiencies, you at least know you could improve by an yet-unknown amount, but if you don't you know you'd have to learn a lot before you can improve on it.

Comment: My experience when doing the same with the x86 Delphi compiler is that you might stand to gain around 5% performance. Most of that comes from saving the FWAIT instruction until the very end of the function. Are you sure that you have found the bottlenecks of your app? How did you identify the bottlenecks? Can you share the results of your profiling?

Comment: I also wonder why those booleans appear in what looks like a simple matrix multiply function. What is the purpose there? Branching is to be avoided.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan at_delnan. Frankly speaking, I didn't spot any concrete evidence that app bottlenecks is due to forementioned function/procs and I'm not the original writer of those portion of code. My wild guess and simple reasoning was that, since app is slow when compared to other 2D/3D apps and those apps uses assembly in their similar functions then bottleneck must be in non-assembly procs/functions.

Comment: It is pointless optimising that which you do not know to be your bottleneck. Step 1 is to locate your bottleneck.

Comment: Best thing to do now it to compile it in 64-bit modus. Than you'll be using the SSE instructions instead of the x87 ones.

Comment: David's advice is exactly, and the only, correct solution.  Trying to optimize without profiling is like a doctor trying to do surgery both blind and without ever having done a diagnosis.  Tools you can use : http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Profiling

Comment: Matrix operations are such basic must-have thing that there should be tons of super optimized code for this task already available. Hardware support for vector operations appeared decades ago. I'd recommend do a web research and find some code that already does quite well what you need (unless you want to learn the subject by doing it yourself..). BTW GDI+,DirectDraw has that built-in, but I don't know what is your target platform

Comment: @xmojmr  There are indeed optimized libraries. But if the matrix operations are not in the application's performance bottleneck, then doing all of the work to incorporate them will not be effective in the context of the given application.

Comment: There are libraries which uses ASM in their codes, GLScene matrix/vector operations comes in mind, no doubt about the fact that I have to find the correct diagnosis and pave my way toward that. Seems that profiling is what I need.

Comment: Aside from using a /current/ (2.6.x) version, experiment with FPC/trunk. It is fairly stable at the moment, and has considerably more optimization options

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort It's good to hear that,

Answer (score 0):

It's best to profile your code first so you know what to focus on improving.

You may also want to consider using something like [OpenCL](http://wiki.freepascal.org/OpenCL)

When it comes to matrix operations and the others you described, you can usually benefit from using the GPU. Even many regular CPUs support OpenCL now. You can take advantage of doing the same instruction on multiple datapoints in parallel. See [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)

Just try to avoid using lots of branching if statements in your kernels.